# How to widen the window of the modal?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

The modal is like this:

[modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVGUg.png)

I would really like to widen the window so that it is pleasant to the user.

How to do this on Bootstrap or CSS, please?

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-error-title">Une erreur s'est produite</h4>
   <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close button" aria-describedby="modal-title" (click)="close()"></button>  
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">type </th>
               <th scope="col" style="width: 20%">Code erreur </th>
               <th scope="col" style="width: 60%">Message </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>Warning</td>
               <td>SCH00</td>
               <td>COMAddError in error for RTG SCH00</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="close()">Fermer la fenêtre </button>
</div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#optional-sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding `.modal-lg` or `mx-5` and if even that is not enough for you, you can declare `id` for elements and can manually increase their size or just add more padding if you would.